# how to start 3 apps at the same time

Tags: empathy, skype

I found an interesting [project (skypathy)](http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/project-skypathy/)
what this project does is runs skype via empathy (sky-pathy)
with the help from a pidgin plugin that also works with empathy
**pidgin-skype** i installed everything like so

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype skype-wrapper empathy pidgin-skype 
sudo apt-get remove sni-qt
```

then run the skype first. then skype-wrapper give permissions and empathy
i am making an .desktop file but don't now how to start them all one after the other.
and the sudo apt-get remove sni-qt should remove my skype icon from the unity-panel bit it doesn't.this is how my .desktop file looks like

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=skypathy
GenericName=IM Client
X-GNOME-FullName=Skypathy full Internet Messaging
Comment=Chat on Google Talk, Facebook, skype, MSN and many other chat services
Exec=skype skype-wrapper empathy
Icon=/home/USERNAME/Desktop/skypathy.png
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;InstantMessaging;
```

i also tried to change the "Exec=" to a scripts that runs the apps

```
skype && skype-wrapper && empathy
```

but when it runs skype it wont go to skype-wrapper until skype is closed same as when runnin skype-wrapper it wont go to empathy until skype-wrapper is closed

this is the icon i used (just for fun)[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G8RB.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run it in the background. That is achieved using the single "&" character after a command:

```
(skype &
sleep 3
skype-wrapper &
sleep 5
empathy &)
```

The commands have to be separated by a new line character (unless someone else has a better idea).

Comment: thanks it kind of worked. when running the commands they all start together but empathy doesn't connect until i restart it i think skype-wrapper needs a second to load then start empathy also i had a problem with the skype icon it supposed to be  in the messaging menu when removing the sni-qt package. but it still remains in the unity-panel.

Comment: @blade19899 Try again, I added the sleep commands. I don't know how to fix the problems with skype / sni-qt though. I use [google video chat](http://www.google.com/chat/video) and [jitsi](http://jitsi.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
skype && skype-wrapper && empathy
```

to:

```
skype& skype-wrapper & empathy
```

Comment: This will still wait for skype to exit. The difference is && will only continue if the previous command "succeeded" (returns code 0) whereas ; will run the next command regardless. But it still waits for the previous one.